# Trouble with STL map and pointers

Tags: c++

```
typedef map<char,string> someMap;
someMap *mapPtr=someClass.getMap();
*(mapPtr)["a"].length();
```

The last line of this code fails. What should I to in order to make this work?

Comment: "The last line of this code fails. What should I do in order to make this work?" don't use pointers in the first place (return by value or by reference).

Comment: @daknok_t that's not necessarily something you can control though

Comment: @user1203803 not helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    (*mapPtr)['a'].length();
```

the `*` operator has a lower precedence than `[]` so you have to but that in brackets.  Also `"a"` is the string literal (char array) whereas you want `'a'`

A complete list of operator precedences in C++ can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1):

`[]` has higher precedence than `*`

This is likely what you intend:

`(*mapPtr)["a"].length();`